# LIBGDX Healthbar not showing up

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a game as a small project. 
I want to add 2 healthbars(2 players one for each player)

I got an hud where I want to put a healthbar now its a number, which is doll. In the picture below the black box is the HUD.

I found this on here on the site but doesnt work.

```
SpriteBatch batch;

Texture texture, texture2;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    initTestObjects();

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(texture, 10, 10, 3000, 20);

    batch.draw(texture2, 10, 10, 2500, 20);
    //batch.end();
}


private void initTestObjects() {

    int width = 1;
    int height = 1;
    Pixmap pixmap = createProceduralPixmap(width, height, 255, 1, 0);
    Pixmap pixmap2 = createProceduralPixmap(width, height, 255, 255, 0);

    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    texture2 = new Texture(pixmap2);

}

private Pixmap createProceduralPixmap(int width, int height, int r, int g, int b) {
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);

    pixmap.setColor(r, g, b, 1);
    pixmap.fill();

    return pixmap;
}
```

as you can see https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1qnwruyr2c1k5h/NoHP.PNG?dl=0 there is no hp drawn.

The rest of the code of the class. http://pastebin.com/AqNFarZ1

Thanks in before hand :)